# Complex ViewModel is null on form post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I have a problem with a systems I'm developing using a complex ViewModel to build a questionnaire.  When the form is submitted, the ViewModel being returned is null.

I've seen posts about the parameter name of the viewmodel not being the same as the ViewModel itself and also some of the parameter names within the ViewModel causing problems, but I can't see anything untoward.

Any thoughts?

Thanks
Simon

The ViewModel looks like this:

```
public class SurveysViewModel
{
    public Survey SurveyDetails { get; set; }
    [AdditionalMetadata("HideLabel", true)]
    public List<QuestionSet> SurveyQuestions { get; set; }
}
```

The classes within them look like this:

```
public class Survey
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string SurveyName { get; set; }
    public int IntroId { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string IntroName { get; set; }
    public string Intro { get; set; }
    public string Conclusion { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionSet
{
    public int? SubQuestionOf { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public bool RepeatPerUser { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public string Q_Text { get; set; }
    public string SubText { get; set; }
    public string TableTitle { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public string Format { get; set; }
    public string OptionsGroup { get; set; }
    public string DBViewName { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public int? Minimum { get; set; }
    public int? Maximum { get; set; }
    public int? Interval { get; set; }
    public int SelectedOption { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

The Post method in the controller is as follows:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [ActionName("CompleteSurvey")]
    public ActionResult CompleteSurvey_Post(SurveysViewModel vm)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          //Do something in here
        }
    }
```

But the ViewModel (vm) shows the two parts as null.

I should add that the questions within the questionset are various types (e.g. dropdowns or range inputs) which inherit from QuestionSet for instance:

```
public class QuestionSet_DropDown : QuestionSet
{
    public QuestionSet_DropDown(QuestionSet question)
    {
        Header = question.Header;
        Id = question.Id;
        QuestionText = question.QuestionText;
        Q_Text = question.Q_Text;
        AllowMultiSelect = false;

    }
    public List<Answer> Options { get; set; }
    public bool AllowMultiSelect { get; set; }
}

@model SurveysViewModel

<h1>Survey Page</h1>
<form action="/PublicAuthSurvey/CompleteSurvey" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
  <div class="survey">
     @{ var questions = Model.SurveyQuestions; }
      @Html.EditorForModel(questions)
  </div>
  <input class="btn btn-lg btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit Results" />
</form>
```

Comment: That all depends on how you submit your data. Add this to the question

Comment: Please show your view code to see if your view page causing the problem. Make sure you're including `@model` directive and form contents which contains postback trigger (e.g. submit button).

Comment: I've added the view - as you can see it's very simple but I have custom editors for my question types.

Comment: Just thinking about my EditorForModel is only using the questions element of my model. Is that why?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I'm pretty sure you need to have at least the ID number of the survey type being submitted along with the rest of the form. It doesn't have to be on display though, it can be in a hidden div or similar. I found a helper class recently for this, I'll try hunt out the URL for you.

Comment: Sorry, the helper class I was referring to is for something slightly different I think, but it is related to binding to lists so it may be useful to you. https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Comment: Thanks Marmalade - I changed my EditorForModel to use the entire model rather than just the questions element but that didn't make any difference - still returning as a null viewmodel.

Comment: I'm getting there - slowly!  I have some quite complex question types and when I remove those, I can see the model is populated on post.  I think I need to rationalise those somehow to mimic the model and still display the way I want to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments thus far.  I finally managed to get there.

I was using a mixture of nested complex types, inheritance and custom editor templates and when you look at the mark up on the page, some of the inputs that were created didn't map back to the model correctly.

If anyone else is reading this looking for a solution, use the developer tools to check the name of the inputs your editor templates have created and make sure they map back to your model properly.  For me, one type was not mapping correctly so the whole model was being returned as null.

After much removal of hair, I think I'm just about there!

Thanks
Simon